# Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 Overheating

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, cpu

I'm angry with Windows. I replaced him with Ubuntu 12.04. I downloaded an Ubuntu 12.04(amd64).iso and made it bootable by USB stick.

I removed W7 and installed Ubuntu. 
Though, I was feeling my notebook overheating and making some extra noise(didnt do on W7)

I have a Samsung 700G7A
64-bit
2 Tera HDD
16 GB Ram
Intel® Core™ i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz × 8 
[AMD/ATI] Blackcomb [Radeon HD 6970M/6990M]

I updated the kernel, tried to use gnome, but nothing changed..
Using Gnome on Ubuntu 12.04

[image]

SO I removed 12.04 and installed Ubuntu 14.04. Didnt see any difference.

[image]

If I install Google Chrome, it goes from 61 to 78C. Thats pretty weird.

I cleaned up inside my computer and windows was just fine.

I just want to use Ubuntu.

Comment: The screenshot indicates each core is only 50C which is really good for the processor you have. Why exactly are you worried about these temperatures they are well within the limits of the hardware itself.  Given that the maximum temperature is 100 C ( this is the temperature of the actual processor itself which isn't measureable ) but all the same you are well within the limits.

Comment: Im actually worried about temp1 and temp2 temperatures that are from CPU and motherboard I guess.. it went from 61 to 78 only by installing GOogle Chrome.

Comment: The CPU temperatures are well below the limits of the hardware, as I indicated, the process has a 100 C limit and will shut itself down to prevent damage which you made no mention of it doing.  As for the other temperatures they are well within the limits of your hardware given that its a laptop.

Comment: **Why are you asking this question again though?**

Answer (score 0):

It happened once for me. But I have Nvidia GPU in my notebook. I solved the heating issue by installing Nvidia drivers for Ubuntu.

Did you installed AMD GPU Driver for Ubuntu? Try that one.

Comment: Yes dude, I typed fglrxinfo and got:daniel@daniel-Ubuntu:~$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6900M Series
OpenGL version string: 4.3.12798 Compatibility Profile Context 13.35.1005